# Split character column by date into new date column

Tags: date, character, stringr

I am working with a character vector describing locations and dates. I am trying to separate the vector into a location and date column. The character line does not possess clear rules for using stringer or separate functions, however, the character line always ends with a date like "April 20." I have tried separating on months of the year, but then lose the month name.

#sample

```
    locations <- c("Molino November 28.", "Wolf River Bridge December 4.")
    df <- data.frame(locations)e here
```

#using stringr produces error

```
     df1[c('location', 'date')] <- str_split_fixed(df$locations, c('November', 'December'), 2)
```

Trying to produce vectors like below:

```
Location                      Date
"Molino"                  "November 28"
"Wolf River Bridge"       "December 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use separate_wider_regex:

```
separate_wider_regex(df, locations, patterns = c(locations = ".*(?=\\s\\w+\\s\\d+\\.)", "\\s", date = "\\w+\\s\\d+", "\\.")) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%B %d"))

# Output:
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  locations         date      
  <chr>             <date>    
1 Molino            2023-11-28
2 Wolf River Bridge 2023-12-04
```

The date pattern is " [word] [number].", so in the locations regex, we look ahead for this, getting everything up to that point.